# Change multiple document fields does not work in ES 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a doc:

```
"_index": "boe_bpm",
"_type": "document",
"_id": "3215951",
"_version": 1,
"_source": {
    "title": "aaaa",
    "process": {
        "tasks": [{
                "class": "value1",
                "id": 1
            }, {
                "class": "value1",
                "id": 2
            },

            ... {
                "class": "value1",
                "id": 1000
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

I want to change  value of `process/tasks` but failed  ,my code:

```
    List ll = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            ll.add(i);
        }

    params.put("ids", ll);
    params.put("classParam", "xxxxzzzaaa");
    client.prepareUpdate("boe_bpm", "document", "3215951").setScript(new Script(
                        "def items = ctx._source.items.findAll{ it.id in ids}; if (items) { for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) { items[i]['class']=classParam; } }",
                        ScriptType.INLINE, null, params))
                .get();
```

There are no error or exception information.

Why it does not work?how to change my code?

Comment: Do you get an error or nothing is being updated?

Comment: no error or exception information returned and nothing is being updated.I do not know why.

Comment: According to your sample document above, `ctx._source.items` should be `ctx._source.process.tasks`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your sample document above, `ctx._source.items` should be `ctx._source.process.tasks`, right?

And you script can be much simpler if you leverage Groovy to its fullest like this:

```
ctx._source.process.tasks.findAll { it.id < 1000 }.each { it['class'] = classParam }
```

So your update code would read:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("classParam", "xxxxzzzaaa");
String script = "ctx._source.process.tasks.findAll { it.id < 1000 }.each { it['class'] = classParam }";
client.prepareUpdate("boe_bpm", "document", "3215951")
  .setScript(new Script(script, ScriptType.INLINE, null, params))
            .get();
```